# Execution time optimization with serial execution of jar and c++ executable

Tags: java, python, c++, shell, stanford-nlp

I am using co-reference resolution where we are amalgamating various functionality and executing them one by one to get final result.

All executable are from different opensource provider. Implementing all functionalities like NER, POS, Parsing etc are not feasible for now. So I have to use the existing (and Stanford is best suitable for this).

Issue is, it is taking much time to execute all one by one and give result. Around 25-30 seconds

**Everytime I execute, it compiles linked files and give output. Is that anyway to reduce this execution time?**

All commands are in `.sh` shell script and I am executing it via python file.

Here are set of commands being executed

1. Getting NER (Named entity recognization)

   java -mx700m -cp $1/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier $1/classifiers/ner-eng-ie.crf-3-all2008-distsim.ser.gz -textFile $2

(java jar file)

2. Getting POS (Part of speech)

   java -mx300m -classpath $1/stanford-postagger.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model $1/models/bidirectional-wsj-0-18.tagger -textFile $2

(java jar file)

3. Using minipar parse for parsing the text

   tools/minipar/pdemo/pdemo -p tools/minipar/data/ < $1 > $1.minipar

(c++ executable)

4. Detecting mentions

   java MentionDetection $1

(class file)

5. java CreateNPSpan $1 $1.pred

(class file)

6. creating feature file

   java -cp .:edu.mit.jwi.jar CherryPick cr $1
7. cr joint model

   tools/svmrank/svm_classify $1 modelrank > $1.entities

(c++ executable)

8. Getting response

   java MakeResponse $1

(classfile)

Comment: I suggest you time each of the components to see which is taking the most time and use a CPU and memory profiler to see how the code can be changed to make it faster.  BTW It would be marginally faster if you didn't start/stop so many Java processes, you could have one process do the end to end solution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: thanks for this suggestion. Actually `stanford` and other opensource community have provided these executables. Each of different functionality

Comment: You can still put them into one program by calling them from a `main` you created.